# [NAV/ASP.NET]Web Service Credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, authentication, iis

I have created a Dynamics NAV 2016 Codeunit Web Service (SOAP Stream) which I want to consume in an ASP.NET 4 web application.

For authentication I need to use the Windows Credentials. This is a very brief code example.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace CleanWebApp
{
    using GridRef; //Web Reference
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Grid grid = new Grid(); //New instance of the Web Service
                grid.UseDefaultCredentials = true; //Use the DefaultCredentials (system credentials of the application)

                //Create a table rows and cells based on the return values of the Codeunit functions
                int columns = grid.SendColumnsToWeb();
                int rows = grid.SendRowsToWeb();

                for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
                {
                    TableRow tr = new TableRow();
                    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
                    {
                        TableCell tc = new TableCell();
                        tc.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(grid.SendDescToWeb(j + 1, i + 1)));
                        tr.Cells.Add(tc);
                    }
                    DynamicTable.Rows.Add(tr);
                }
            }
[...]
```

When I run this code from Visual Studio the web application gets started via IIS Express and everything works fine.
Now I publish this project to my hard drive and run it with the IIS Windows feature. When exploring my web site I get a `http status 401 unauthorized` error.

Windows Authentification is enabled in my IIS-Manager.

In the web.config file in the system.web block I added `<authentication mode="Windows">`.

When I provide hard-coded credentials (user, password, domain) and use this code for authentication `grid.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(user, password, domain);` everything works as it should, except that the credentials are provided programtically...

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check your Internet Explorer settings? Under the security tab you can adjust the security zone. There is an option for user authentication which you should check out.